# Error 503 Service unavailable Uploading base64 to mysql BLOB

Tags: node.js, heroku

For several days I have been having problems trying to get my Node.Js app deployed on heroku to save a base64 string to Mysql database as BLOB. It prompts the CORS error 503 problem and hence I am in a fix and cannot do anything any longer. I have to wait for several hours before i can do anything and still i cannot be able to save the base 64 string to Mysql (ClearDB)

Here is what my backend Node.JS Looks like

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
 app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    var origin = req.get('origin'); 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
});


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));

app.get('/api/',function(req , res){
    return res.send({error: false,message: 'hello'})
});

var dbConn = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    user: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
});

// dbConn.connect();
module.exports = dbConn;

//Functions
//register
app.post('/api/register',function(req,res){
    var postData = req.body;
    dbConn.query('INSERT INTO icloneusers SET ?', postData, function (error,results,fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        return res.send({error:false, data: results, message: 'OK'});
    });
});

//login
app.post('/api/login', function(req,res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    dbConn.query('SELECT * FROM icloneusers WHERE username = ? AND password =?', [username,password], function (error, results, fields){
        if(results.length > 0){
            return res.send({error:false, message: 'OK'});
        }else{ 
            return res.send({error: false, message: 'Incrorrect Login Details'});
        }
    });
});

app.post('/api/posts',function(req,res){
    var postData = req.body;
    dbConn.query('INSERT INTO icloneuserspost SET ?', postData, function (error,results,fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        return res.send({error:false, data: results, message: 'OK'});
    });
});

app.get('/api/posts/:username', function(req,res){
    let username = req.params.username;
    
    if(!username){
        return res.status(400).send({error: true, message: 'Please provide username'});
    }
    dbConn.query('SELECT * FROM icloneuserspost WHERE username =?', username,function(error, results, fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        return res.send({ error:false, data: results, message: 'posts.' });
    });
});


app.post('/api/createpost',function(req,res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var base64str = req.body.base64str;
    var post = req.body.post;

    dbConn.query('INSERT INTO icloneuserspost (username, base64str, post) VALUES (?,?,?)',[username, base64str,post],function (error, results, fields){
        if (error) throw error;
        return res.send({error: false,data: results, message: 'Post Created'});
        });
});


app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('App running on Port: '+port);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Immediately I call `/api/createpost`, i start getting This CORS error, and all the modules stop working immediately.

Now i am getting Error 503 from everyway possible using that backend server. Please I need advice, is there something I amnot doing correctly? kindly advice.

**Edits**

Looking thru my logs now,I see this As error

^

```
2021-10-28T06:21:46.942991+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-10-28T06:21:46.942992+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'username' cannot be null
2021-10-28T06:21:46.942993+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943002+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Query.ErrorPacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943002+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943002+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser._parsePacket (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943003+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Parser.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943003+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.write (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943003+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943004+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943004+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943004+00:00 app[web.1]:     at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943005+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943005+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Pool.query (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943005+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/iassclone.js:86:12
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943006+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943007+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943007+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943007+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943007+00:00 app[web.1]:     at urlencodedParser (/app/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:100:7) {
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943007+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943008+00:00 app[web.1]:   errno: 1048,
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943008+00:00 app[web.1]:   sqlMessage: "Column 'username' cannot be null",
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943008+00:00 app[web.1]:   sqlState: '23000',
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943008+00:00 app[web.1]:   index: 0,
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943008+00:00 app[web.1]:   sql: 'INSERT INTO icloneuserspost (username, base64str, post) VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL)'
2021-10-28T06:21:46.943009+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-10-28T06:21:46.951291+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-10-28T06:21:46.951459+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-10-28T06:21:46.954188+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! iassgb@1.0.0 start: `node iassclone.js`
2021-10-28T06:21:46.954234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-10-28T06:21:46.954289+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2021-10-28T06:21:46.954327+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the iassgb@1.0.0 start script.
2021-10-28T06:21:46.954364+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-10-28T06:21:46.957295+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-10-28T06:21:46.957381+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-10-28T06:21:46.957416+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-10-28T06_21_46_954Z-debug.log
2021-10-28T06:21:47.069221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-28T06:21:47.145896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-10-28T06:21:47.188605+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-28T06:21:49.154572+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-10-28T06:21:50.325243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-28T06:21:50.051231+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-10-28T06:21:50.051244+00:00 app[web.1]: > iassgb@1.0.0 start /app
2021-10-28T06:21:50.051244+00:00 app[web.1]: > node iassclone.js
2021-10-28T06:21:50.051245+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-10-28T06:21:50.197769+00:00 app[web.1]: App running on Port: 44770
```

Which says Column username cannot be NULL, and i utilise the username from localstorage.getItem() saved in browser but it still tells me it is NULL.
the post request to save the posts in the DB looks like this :

```
function createNewPost(){
    let username = localStorage.getItem('userinfo');
    let base64str = localStorage.getItem('postImage');
    let item = {username, post, base64str};
    fetch('https://m2d3srv.herokuapp.com/api/createpost',{
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(item)
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
        if(responseJson.message ==='Post Created'){
            alert("Post Created");
        }else{
            alert(responseJson.message);
        }
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.error(error);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

```
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
```

That was the challenge, changing to `'Content-Type': 'application/json',`

Fixed it. It now posts the base64 as BLOB